# Moving Sprite issues

Tags: python, pygame

When this part of the code has been run, it shows the sprite however when the arrow keys are pressed nothing moves, ive tried to use print statements to attempt to debug but nothing has come up, what is the issue and how do i solve it? Here ive added everything relating to the movement in my program the other files include the screen and the exit loop

```
from spritechanges import *
from lklk import *
import pygame
import time
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0, 0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 120

# Create a surface/image and draw a circle onto it.
sprite_image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
pygame.draw.circle(sprite_image, WHITE, [25, 25], 20)
# Create surface/image draw a line onto it
width = 40
height = 60


# Create an instance of the Sprite class.
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()  # platform
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.platform = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.platform.fill(WHITE)
        # set a reference to the image rect
        self.rect = self.platform.get_rect()
        # Assign the global image to `self.image`.
        self.image = sprite_image

        # Create a rect which will be used as blit
        # position and for the collision detection.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Set the rect's center to the passed `pos`.
        self.rect.center = pos
        self._vx = 0
        self._vy = 0
        # Assign the pos also to these attributes.
        self._spritex = pos[0]
        self._spritey = pos[1]
        # set of sprites sprite can bump against
        self.level = None

def update(self):
    self._gravity = 99
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        if self._vx > 0:
            self.rect.right = block.rect.left
        elif self._vx < 0:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = block.rect.right
    self.rect.y += self.change_y

    # Check and see if we hit anything
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self._vy > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
        elif self._vy < 0:
            self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self._vy = 0

    self._vx = 0
    self.rect.y += 2
    platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    self.rect.y -= 2

    # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
    if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= H:
        self._xy = -10

        # Player-controlled movement:


def go_left(self):
    """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
    self._vx = -6


def go_right(self):
    """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
    self._vx = 6


def stop(self):
    """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
    self._vx = 0

    # Adjust the position.
    self._spritex += self._vx
    self._spritey += self._vy

    # And update the center of the rect.
    self.rect.center = (self._spritex, self._spritey)

sprite = Sprite([400, 550])

active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite.level = current_level

sprite.rect.x = 340
sprite.rect.y = H - sprite.rect.height
active_sprite_list.add(sprite)
done = True
while not done:
    events()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                sprite.go_left()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                sprite.go_right()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                sprite.jump()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and sprite.change_x < 0:
                sprite.stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and sprite.change_x > 0:
                sprite.stop()
                # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
        if sprite.rect.right > W:
            sprite.rect.right = W

            # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if sprite.rect.left < 0:
            sprite.rect.left = 0
        DS.fill(BLACK)

        # Blit the sprite's image at the sprite's rect.topleft position.
        DS.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's difficult or impossible to find the cause of the error.

Comment: This is the minimal i can add so i dont get what you mean ive added the subroutine for the movement thats it but if i posted the whole code all of you will downvote my question

Comment: It's too minimal. We need a more complete example.

Comment: you have wrong indentions - use button `{}` to correctly format code in question.

Comment: create minimal working example so we could run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some code in the `stop` method that should be in the `update` method. The jump code needs to be in a separate `jump` method. Also, call `active_sprite_list.update()` in the main while loop to update all contained sprites and `active_sprite_list.draw(DS)` to draw them. Here's a complete working example:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
sprite_image = pygame.Surface((50, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(sprite_image, (90, 100, 200), [25, 25], 25)
W, H = DS.get_size()


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super(Platform, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill((90, 90, 120))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))


class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = sprite_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        self._vx = 0
        self._vy = 0
        self._spritex = pos[0]
        self._spritey = pos[1]
        self.level = None
        self._gravity = .9

    def update(self):
        # Adjust the x-position.
        self._spritex += self._vx
        self.rect.centerx = self._spritex  # And update the rect.

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self._vx > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self._vx < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
            self._spritex = self.rect.centerx  # Update the position.

        # Adjust the y-position.
        self._vy += self._gravity  # Accelerate downwards.
        self._spritey += self._vy
        self.rect.centery = self._spritey  # And update the rect.

        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self._vy > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self._vy < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
            self._spritey = self.rect.centery  # Update the position.
            # Stop our vertical movement
            self._vy = 0

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2

        # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= H:
            self._vy = -17

    def go_left(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
        self._vx = -3

    def go_right(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
        self._vx = 3

    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
        self._vx = 0


sprite = Sprite([60, 60])

active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group(sprite)
sprite.level = pygame.sprite.Group(
    Platform(20, 400, 200, 20), Platform(220, 300, 20, 120),
    Platform(220, 300, 300, 20))
active_sprite_list.add(sprite.level)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                sprite.go_left()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                sprite.go_right()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                sprite.jump()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and sprite._vx < 0:
                sprite.stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and sprite._vx > 0:
                sprite.stop()
    # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
    if sprite.rect.right > W:
        sprite.rect.right = W
        # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
    if sprite.rect.left < 0:
        sprite.rect.left = 0

    active_sprite_list.update()

    DS.fill((50, 50, 50))
    # Blit the sprite's image at the sprite's rect.topleft position.
    active_sprite_list.draw(DS)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now, however to make more platforms shall i make a for loop because ive tried fiddling with the platforms and try to add more but it just changes the position of it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing. Better post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem?

self._vx = 0

Whenever the user lets off the keyboard, you end up adjusting the position by zero?

Comment: Ive removed that part and it doesnt make a difference?